# How use Regex from uncheck all files by file formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

i need uncheck many files from this `HTML` with `JQuery`
**HTML:**

```
<div class="well">
  <h2>Select you files</h2>
  <table id="list-files" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th width="10px"><input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="checked"></th>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>Size</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="0" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="Visit thist Web.com.txt"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>34.0 iB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="1" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.mkv"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>8.8 GiB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="selectedFiles" style="display: table-row;">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="2" checked=""></td>
        <td>
          <div><span class="pull-left">The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT/</span><span style="padding-top:1px;padding: 0 2px;display:block;overflow:hidden"><input style="width:100%;color:#c8c8c8;background-color:transparent;padding:0px;margin:0px" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="The.Blind.Side.2009.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.nfo"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>5.4 KiB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
var inp=$("tr input");
var r="Visit thist Web.com.txt";
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
 if(inp[i].value == r){
  inp[i-1].checked = false;
 }
}
```

> How to improve this code?

This `script` uncheck only `var r="Visit thist Web.com.txt";` and i need uncheck all files with **.txt**! it's true this example only has one .txt, but that usually changes, even the order.
I would also like to unmark files with .nfo, .url, jpg, gif that's why I suppose it would be best to do it with regex

for `tampermonkey` on `chrome`

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jquery `filter` function with a regex. The regex:

```
/\.txt$/gi
```

The regex will match the literal string: `'.txt'` at the end.

**How to use:**

```
var inp=$("tr input").filter( function (index)
{
    return /\.txt$/gi.test($(this).val());
}).closest('tr').find('td:first-child input').prop('checked', false);
```

This will set the checked property to false on matched elements.

To uncheck other file types, you can change the regex to:

```
/\.txt$|\.nfo$|\.url$|\.jpg$|\.gif$/gi
```

**Edit**: I have studied your html a bit closer and changed my code, hope it Works now.

**Edit2**:

Actually you can also use your original code extended to include regex:

```
var inp=$("tr input");
var regex = /\.txt$|\.nfo$|\.url$|\.jpg$|\.gif$/gi;
for (i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
 if (regex.test(inp[i].value)) {
  inp[i-1].checked = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: excellent friend! I think your code is very good What I can be doing wrong? I put your code in tampermonkey but it does not uncheck.. I even charge it in jsfiddle.net and it does not work! I'm doing something wrong.. please if someone helps me I'm very new to this :( . thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much Poul Bak! my code improved by you works excellent. thank again dude